# Upper and lower limit of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let u be this vector: $u=(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_6),u\in \mathbb{R}^6$ and  $\Vert u \Vert \le20 $
We are asked to find the limits $a,b$ such as: $$ a\le 10u_{1}-2u_{2}+9u_{3}-2u_{4}+4u_{5}+7u_{6} \le b $$ 
I was thinking Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but i didn't manage to connect it with $u_1,u_2 \dots,u_5$
Also i know that: $$( u_{1} +u_{2} +...+u_{n})^2 \leqslant n \cdotp {\left( u_{1}^{2} +u_{2}^{2} +...+u_{n}^{2}\right)} \text{ ,given that: } u= (u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n),u\in \mathbb{R}^n$$ but i had the same problem with the  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
How should i work on this kind of problems?

Comment: You can just write plain text for the non-math bits - you don't need to (and shouldn't) use \text{} that much, if at all. I fixed the first two sentences, you can fix the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.I have edited the question.

Comment: So much nicer. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to disagree with the preivious answer.

**Solution:**
Because the expression $10u_1−2u_2+9u_3−2u_4+4u_5+7u_6$ is linear on $(u1,u2,…,u6).$ from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have that:
$$\vert 10u_1−2u_2+9u_3−2u_4+4u_5+7u_6\vert\le \Vert u\Vert \cdot \Vert (10,-2,9,-2,4,7)\Vert $$

Doing the calculations we have that:
$\Vert (10,-2,9,-2,4,7)\Vert=\sqrt{254}$

Hence, we have that:
$$min\{10u_1−2u_2+9u_3−2u_4+4u_5+7u_6:\Vert u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6\Vert=20\}=-20\cdot \sqrt{254}$$
$$max\{10u_1−2u_2+9u_3−2u_4+4u_5+7u_6:\Vert u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,u_6\Vert=20\}=20\cdot \sqrt{254}$$